# onCreateViewHolder not being called in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

The execution control doesn't seem to go inside the onCreateViewHolder; the data is not getting displayed on the screen.
It seems like onStart and onBindViewHolder are getting called but not the onCreateViewHolder.

I have tried a lot of things, have been trying to figure out the solution for 2 days. I have:
1. Removing setHasFixdSize(true), didn't worked

2. Adding setHasFixedSize(false), didn't worked either
3. Converting the relative layout to frame layout and vice versa.
4. Degrading all the firebase dependencies and use the populateview method. didn't work either
5. Removing all data from firebase didn't work either.
6. I had the adapter inside onStart formerly now I have it in onCreate
7. Retyped my whole code, with a hope it will work, it didn't.

The UsersActivity.java

The Important declarations:

```
private RecyclerView usersList;
private DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UserHolders> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
```

in onCreate:

```
usersList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.user_list);
usersList.setHasFixedSize(false);
usersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Users> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Users>()
    .setQuery(userRef, Users.class)
    .build();

firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Users, UserHolders>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(UserHolders holder, int position, Users model) {
        holder.userName.setText(model.getName());
        holder.userStatus.setText(model.getImage());
        Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.userProfile);
        Toast.makeText(UsersActivity.this, "working onBind", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public UserHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.users_single_layout, viewGroup, false);
        UserHolders userHolders = new UserHolders(view);
        Toast.makeText(UsersActivity.this, "working onCreate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return userHolders;
    }
};
usersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

in onStart()

```
super.onStart();
Toast.makeText(this, "onStart being called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
```

in onStop()

```
super.onStop();
firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
```

The ViewHolder Class:

```
public static class UserHolders extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView userName, userStatus;
    CircleImageView userProfile;

    public UserHolders(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_name);
        userProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_image);
        userStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_status);
    }
}
```

The model class

```
public class Users {

    public String name;
    public String image;
    public String status;

    public Users(){}

    public Users(String name, String image, String status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.status = status;}

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    public String getImage() {return image;}

    public void setImage(String image) {this.image = image;}

    public String getStatus() {return status;}

    public void setStatus(String status) {this.status = status;}
}
```

Firebase dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.2'
```

So I expected that all the toasts will work fine, indicating that complete code is indeed getting compiled.
The toasts inside onBindViewHolder and onStart are getting called but not the one inside the onCreateViewHolder.

So the structure of data is as follows

```
teteatete-c08f9
-Users
  -FxFcc..............
       .- image
       .- name
       .- status
       .- thumb_image
```

I have checked that model class variables have same name as these fields

Comment: Didi you forget to `return size` in `RecyclerView.Adapter` in ` getItemCount()`?

Comment: @NickBapu I didn't know we have to return size. There's no such thing in the documentation

Comment: @NickBapu can you please tell me how to do so. And what is size, here?

Comment: Please add your database structure as JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: Where is your adapter class. I need to see it. If you are using any kind of list then you need to return size of it like: `public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }` this.

Comment: @NickBapu that's the code I have. The FirebaseREcyclerAdapter declaration is included in there.

Comment: Go and change your rules in firebase console

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your code seems perfect.
Did you check the rules in Firebase console?
Turn them from false to true.
Go to your real-time database in Firebase and then, in rules replace false with true.
Then it must work.

Comment: I ran the same code. In my app, and it worked. I am new to StackOverflow, don't know what needs to be commented and what not.